# ActivityGroup with tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost

please can anyone give me sample code,how to use activitygroup which makes tabs alive throughout the application
http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/
i had tried this but i'm not getting
thank u in advance

Comment: Where you stuck? What error you got?

Comment: 03-01 13:28:46.837: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(581): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.redspice.activities/com.redspice.activities.FirstGroup}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.redspice.activities/android.view.CitiesAcitivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?    even after declaring in the manifest file ,i am getting the same exception

Comment: more clearly its stucking here  View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("CitiesActivity", new  
                                            Intent(MenuTab.this,Menu.class)  
                                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))  
                                            .getDecorView();

Answer (score 0):

Have you done as it says and put all of the activities (the activitygroup and any child activities) in the AndroidManifest.xml file?